# Plot Multiple Pandas Dataframes (Groupby Plot)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to plot three dataframe based on their **Total Activity Hours Per Month** so I used the groupby function.

```
df110 = df[df['Attendance Abs Type Code'] == '110']
df120 = df[df['Attendance Abs Type Code'] == '120']

dfWithout110 = df[df['Attendance Abs Type Code'] != '110 ']
dfWithout110120 = dfWithout110[dfWithout110['Attendance Abs Type Code'] != '120']

dfWithout110120Chart = dfWithout110120[["Activity Hours"]].groupby(dfWithout110120["Activity Month"]).sum().plot(kind='bar', width=0.8, title="Total activity hours per month (Without 110 & 120)")
df110chart = df110[["Activity Hours"]].groupby(df110["Activity Month"]).sum().plot(kind='bar', width=0.8, title="Total activity hours per month (110 only)")
df120chart = df120[["Activity Hours"]].groupby(df120["Activity Month"]).sum().plot(kind='bar', title="Total activity hours per month (120 only)")
```

Download link for the dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdSsP8BM4PVNh8m2kW7244NOo75lNUT7/view?usp=sharing

Here is some sample data from the dataframe:

[image]

Please take a look at the attached picture.

[image]

What I really wanted is actually a stacked barchart like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a copy-pastable version of your data?

Comment: Alright I'll upload my dataset csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hue` parameter in `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

df['hue'] = df["Attendance Abs Type Code"]
df.loc[~df['hue'].isin(['110', '120']), 'hue'] = 'Other'
df = df.groupby(['Activity Month', 'hue'])['Activity Hours'].sum().reset_index()

sns.barplot(x='Activity Month', y='Activity Hours', hue='hue', data=df)
```

Comment: Hi. It's working but I'm not really sure about the correctness of the result. The graph for Other should be higher right? Since the total monthly activity hours for the "Other" is much higher than the other two (110 and 120).

Comment: @FirdhausSaleh You need to groupby and sum first.

Comment: I tried to code them but I failed. Would u mind helping me with code to groupby and sum first please?